# Is "squared up to" natural in this context?

Tags: expressions

The man shoved me hard into a wall and then laughed at me. I recovered and squared up to him, but then a bouncer came over and pulled us apart.

Is "squared up to" a completely natural expression to use here? Or what else could be used?

Answer (score 1):

It means after recovering they stood up to him, shoulders square across from shoulders, as if in preparation for another conflict/altercation. It is a bit old fashioned but serves the purpose admirably.